# Retrofit gives onFailure Callback When Using LiveData - Failed to invoke public androidx.lifecycle.LiveData() with no args

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

```
I/System.out: Failure -> Failed to invoke public androidx.lifecycle.LiveData() with no args
```

I am fetching data from the API. I am trying to use MVVM, i am new in MVVM. So i call the api from the ViewModel and i return the data in the method. I am observing that method from my MainActivity. But i don't know why is is giving me the follow error.

Retrofit goes in the failure callback. But it was going in the success callback when i was not using LiveData.

```
I/System.out: Failure -> Failed to invoke public androidx.lifecycle.LiveData() with no args
```

### My View Model

```js
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

  private ApiInterface apiInterface;
  private LiveData < List < Feature >> featuresList;

  public MainViewModel() {
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    getEqData();
    featuresList = new MutableLiveData < > ();
  }

  public void getEqData() {

    apiInterface.getTodos().enqueue(new Callback < EarthquakeData > () {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call < EarthquakeData > call, Response < EarthquakeData > response) {
        featuresList = response.body().features;
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call < EarthquakeData > call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Failure -> " + t.getMessage());
      }
    });
  }

  public LiveData < List < Feature >> returnEqData() {
    return featuresList;
  }

}
```

### MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final String TAG = "sagar";
  private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
  private RecyclerView rvEarthquake;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rvEarthquake = findViewById(R.id.rvEarthquake);
    EarthquakeAdapter adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this);
    rvEarthquake.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rvEarthquake.setAdapter(adapter);

    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mainViewModel.returnEqData().observe(this, new Observer < List < Feature >> () {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(List < Feature > features) {
        adapter.setData(features);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setValue or postValue to set value in featuresList like below

```
featuresList.setValue(response.body().features);
```